# Bootstrapping Juju 1.13 to private OpenStack

Tags: juju, cloud, openstack

I've been trying for ages now to get Juju to bootstrap with my private OpenStack installation. Starting with 1.11 I've been stuck with this error during bootstrap:

```
error: cannot start bootstrap instance: no "precise" images in RegionOne with arches [amd64 i386]
```

In 1.11 I was able to use 'juju image-metadata' to create the index.json and imagemetadata.json files for upload to Swift (though I still never got past the error), but this command no longer exists in 1.13, and I can't find any mention of a replacement.

Is there a way to bootstrap a private OpenStack cloud with Juju 1.13? And if so, is there any documentation to guide me through from scratch? I'm eager to learn how to develop Juju services, but I can't even get it bootstrapped!

** Edit: The primary issue is that the 'juju image-metadata' is missing, so I'm not able to follow the instructions in the linked question. Is there a replacement to 'juju image-metadata'?

*** I have tried both commands, both report as missing. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: ^^ I'm pretty sure this is the issue you're having, if it's not please edit your question if it didn't work, thanks!

Comment: Did you try `juju-metadata generate-image`?

Comment: Ok it seems that command is also missing for people. I've posted to the list to find out what the problem is, I'll keep the linked question up to date as soon as I know. See also: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2013-August/002814.html